# Suggestion on long running process

Tags: c#, asp.net

My requirement is to create a website in which any number of user can login and click on a button. The task inside that button click will be a long running process (May take hours or days to finish the task). User can logout from the website and  can login occasionally to check the status of the task.Is it good to use the idea in [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12117/Simulate-a-Windows-Service-using-ASP-NET-to-run-sc) article. Please give some suggestion on this.

Thanks.

Comment: Use the web page to post a job to a queue and then have a service that checks the queue and launches long running tasks as needed.

Comment: @Brian Rasmussen: You mean a Windows service?

Answer (score 0):

MSMQ or SQL Service Broker used to communicate with a Windows Service.

```html
asp.net page sends start request
                       ------------MSMQ------------>
                                              Windows service picks up message
                                              and starts the long running job.
                                              As progress is made, it can be
                                              recorded in a "Jobs" table
client checks status from the Jobs table
IIS app pool recycles
.... days pass
                                              Service completes work, and records
                                              the job as Completed

                                              Service might send email notification
                                              with a link to the webpage
client can later retrieve the rendered job
```

If you really *must* stay within IIS, I would still use MSMQ or SQL Server, but you would just have to put your service code in `Application_Start`.

Comment: :Thanks for the suggestion . Its a good idea to use Windows Service. There will be hundred of users in my case.. Can i use different threads for handling different jobs of different users..

Comment: Yes, MSMQ will easily scale to many threads, and also allows you to scale out the service backend to multiple servers, if needed.  MSMQ can easily handle tens of thousands of messages a second on well equipped hardware, so the limiting factor will be your processing needs.